# outlook.com completely doesn't work in firefox

Tags: firefox, outlook.com

I can't move from inbox to junk or another folder.
I can't go to settings. Whenever I click nothing happens.
I've turned off "clear history during closing browser" but outlook.com still doesn't work.
I have to use MS Edge or IE when I want to read my emails.
Does anyone else have the same problem or just me?

**Firefox 40.0.3, no addons, standard plugins**

Comment: Can't replicate it on FF 38. Which version of Firefox are you using? Which addons and extensions?

Comment: I've installed Firefox 40.0.3 without addons. Just standard plugins like Adobe Acrobat or Flash or Google Update but I did not changed anything. The outlook.com has stopped working without understandable reasons for me on this week.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I have the same problem. Running Windows 8. Firefox 55.0.3, just noticed it's 32bit but my cpu is 64bit.